# How to reference JavaScript file in custom ribbon action in SharePoint Online App?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am trying to call JavaScript function into my Custom Ribbon command. I was able to create my Custom Ribbon Action using [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111086/trigger-javascript-on-custom-action-ribbon-menu-item/169543#169543). This perfectly worked for me in creation of Custom Ribbon Action Button and JavaScript Alert also called successfully.

But my question is: Can we call JavaScript function from Custom Ribbon Action from some JS file uploaded in any library in Host Web of SharePoint App? (App may be SharePoint Hosted/Provider Hosted)

I have gone through [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59850/call-javascript-function-for-custom-action-in-app-for-sharepoint-2013/67761#67761) which says it's impossible to call JavaScript function but I am able to call `JavaScript alert()` in `Custom Action`

When I tried following code in my `App Installed` event, I got error like

> The value specified for property Location for custom action
>   {caa19918-a0b1-4cb9-8200-bafc2df31d43} is invalid. The value must be
>   !ScriptLink.

```
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Details"); // or use GetByID or whatever
UserCustomActionCollection collUCA = list.UserCustomActions;

UserCustomAction Scriptaction1 = collUCA.Add();
Scriptaction1.Sequence = 2;
Scriptaction1.ScriptSrc = "~SiteCollection/SiteAssets/Assets/Scripts.js";
Scriptaction1.Title = title;
Scriptaction1.Location = "ScriptLink";
Scriptaction1.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

When I remove `ScriptLink` attribute and add any other attribute then I get error like

> A validation error has occurred.  The ScriptSrc property can only be
>   used when the Location property has the value "ScriptLink".

So, I just wanted to know How can reference JavaScript to my Custom Ribbon Action from C# code?

Comment: hey what is "collUCA" in your code

Comment: Sorry, see updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake you are doing is you are using List's `UserCustomActions`, but here your `ScriptLink` is the part of `SPWeb` or `SPSite`. So you code need to be like

```
 UserCustomAction Scriptaction1 = clientContext.Web.UserCustomActions.Add();
```

instead of

`UserCustomAction Scriptaction1 = collUCA.Add();`

Refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/71e353c2-ea8d-42ba-bdd2-74f98e12ae47/setting-spusercustomaction-with-scriptlink-programmatically?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: Hey this worked like charm :-)