# MenuItemCustomAction popup window problem

Tags: menu-item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction Id="c4b14799-8b38-4951-a24b-1545262b1056.MenuItemCustomAction1"
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="101"
            Location="EditControlBlock"
            Sequence="10001"
            Title="Popup;">

 <UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}&amp;SPSource= {Source}&amp;SPListURLDir={ListUrlDir}&amp;SPItemURL={ItemUrl}" /> 
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

When I try:

```
Url="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank')"
```

It encounters error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': There
>    were errors when validating the App Package.

I want the target site to appear on a new window/ popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem is already asked here:
[Call JavaScript function for a custom action in an app for SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59850/call-javascript-function-for-custom-action-in-app-for-sharepoint-2013)

to cite the same [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220046.aspx):

> CustomAction cannot contain JavaScript: Any UrlActions or
>   CommandActions must be a URL to navigate to. The URL can be
>   parameterized with normal custom actions tokens in addition to the
>   app-specific tokens.

The question is: What do you want to achieve?

When you just want to use a popup then you could open a Modal Dialog and link to a page inside of your app which executes what you want to do (for example open google.com). So your xml should propably look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction Id="c4b14799-8b38-4951-a24b-1545262b1056.MenuItemCustomAction1"
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="101"
            Location="EditControlBlock"
            Sequence="10001"
            Title="Popup;"
            HostWebDialog="true"
            HostWebDialogHeight="500"
            HostWebDialogWidth="800">

        <UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/MyPageToGoogle.aspx" /> 
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

I haven't tested it but it should work. Also described here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/754808/Open-SharePoint-App-Url-as-a-Modal-Dialog-in-Share

**Update:**

In your custom action example you refer to the following page:

```
<UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}...">
```

You say the popup doesn' show the page. Propably you get the following error

[image: iframes no allowed on sharepoint]

if that happens you need check on that page if you have the following tag inside:

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming" runat="server" />
```

If not then inlcude it in the first line of this tag:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming" runat="server" />    
    ** other stuff **    
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I have add HostWebDialog="true" HostWebDialogHeight="500"
            HostWebDialogWidth="800" into the description. However there are blue cruse underline the attributes and say the attributes are not declared. Luckily, the app can be deployed but a dialog with title only.

Comment: TYPO : should be blue curve underline

Comment: the blue curve just means that the xml definition does not know this attribute.

and of course the page you are refering to should exist!

Comment: but the dialog still cannot show the page.

Comment: please refer to my update in the post!